# Does testing the public surface of a class test the behavior of code or the way it is written?

Tags: unit-testing, refactoring

A follow up question to [How do unit tests facilitate refactoring without introducing regressions?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/452449/how-do-unit-tests-facilitate-refactoring-without-introducing-regressions).

I said that integration tests test the behavior of the code, while unit tests, being tied to particular classes and methods, instead test the way it is written. Several answers & comments, if I understand them correctly, challenged this assumption. They seemed to believe that if I write a unit test against the public surface of a class then (even if all dependencies of the said class are mocked?) I am testing the behavior of the code, and not the way it is written. I would be testing the way it is written if I, instead, insisted on testing private methods or write assertions of the sort "assert that method X calls method Y, then method Z".

I find it somewhat surprising - I've always thought about individual classes (and therefore also, in particular, their public surface) as just an implementation detail of the entire application.

This matters because I claimed that unit tests need to be rewritten if refactoring occurs, while others - as I understand them - said that this is only true if *public interface* of a class changes, which happens much rarer than changes of its implementation.

One of the benefits of unit testing, as per proponents, is that it enables or forces a very specific architecture where all methods and classes will be very small. For methods, as per Uncle Bob, this means they should be generally not longer than about 4 lines. For classes this means the Single Responsibility Principle. It is often said that private methods are classes waiting to be factored out, which implies that classes should, generally, have few private methods.

Such an architecture that focuses on tiny methods and classes that come in large numbers seems to me to make it even more true that unit tests test the way code is written and refactoring must invalidate already written unit tests. If methods are extremely tiny it will be rare to limit our changes just to this particular method and this method only. Refactoring will also only rarely be limited just to the implementation of a single class without touching its public surface. Rather, refactoring will rearrange already existing methods and classes, modifying their public surface (and invalidating unit tests written against this public surface). Indeed, one of the most common operations will be splitting a class or a method in two. This will very obviously invalidate the previous interface of a split class (or method), necessitating rewriting of already existing tests.

Am I failing to see something obvious when I treat individual classes as merely an implementation detail? How does the public interface of individual classes and public methods stay constant during refactoring if there are very many very tiny classes and methods? How is writing unit tests for the public interface of each of such tiny classes not testing the way code is written, but rather just testing for its behavior?

Comment: I've read each of your questions, recently, and I've noticed a general misunderstanding of what constitutes a unit test, why people write unit tests, and how best to actually structure code to facilitate testing. It is difficult to answer this question, because there are so many misunderstandings. It almost sounds like "unit testing" has been pounded into your head by others without fully explaining why. Given the effort you've made to write thoughtful questions (despite this community's propensity to down-vote everything), you really seem to be struggling with this.

Comment: Can you [edit] the last paragraph of your question to focus on a single perspective of this? We have too many questions in one post to make this answerable.

Comment: @GregBurghardt Ugh... I'm thinking about it and I'm not sure how to tackle this. The last paragraph has 3 questions. The 3rd one is what I care about, but I need the 2nd one to state the 3rd one. In retrospect I should've probably asked two different questions: (1) does an architecture that follows SRP and prefers very tiny methods mean that classes and methods will be rearranged very often? and (2) in light of (1), are unit tests not fragile? I should probably cut this question to (1), but I can't because it already has two answers covering (2)

Comment: To be honest, the SRP and the number of lines in a class or method is completely irrelevant for unit testing. And remember those are guidelines for designing modules in your application. Use them when they make sense. Discard them with prejudice when they don't.

Comment: I think the questions in the last paragraph are related enough, to be honest.

Comment: @GregBurghardt "*To be honest, the SRP and the number of lines in a class or method is completely irrelevant for unit testing.*" -- Hmm, I thought the general idea was that unit testing forced SRP and tiny methods, which was good since SRP and tiny methods were desirable, and SRP and tiny methods facilitated unit testing, which was good since unit testing was desirable, so according to proponents this was a perfect pair, where each was desirable for its own sake and was also forcing/enabling the other one

Comment: That would actually be a good --- but separate --- question.

Comment: And remember these are all **guidelines**. Even unit testing. You need to use some professional judgement about when to apply all of the tools at your disposal. The SRP, tiny methods, unit tests -- these are all tools. Use them when they make sense, and don't make broad generalizations about them. It can be very situational.

Answer (score 4):

> Does testing the public surface of a class test the behavior of code or the way it is written?

**Yes.**

It depends on how the test was written. A good test is defined by the the [System Under Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_under_test) and the assertion being made about that system. Consider a unit test for a method that returns the result of some calculation. If you `Assert.Equals(42, total)` then you are testing the behavior of whichever class or method calculated the `total`. If instead, you call the same method in your test, but you assert that a method in your mock repository object got called, I would argue the test is verifying how the code is written.

Using the hypothetical example above, let's also assume a repository or data access object is necessary as part of this calculation. Your test could look something like:

```csharp
var mockRepository = new Mock<ISomeRepository>();

mockRepository.Setup(mock => mock.GetValues("foo"));
              .Returns(5);

var calculator = new Calculator(mockRepository.Object);

var total = calculator.GetTotal();

Assert.Equals(42, total);
```

The mock repository is necessary because it is a dependency of the System Under Test. The `mockObject.Setup(...)` line sets up a method call with the predefined return value necessary to verify the expected total.

Now it comes time to refactor. The `GetTotal` method is a hot mess, and you decide to pull some of the logic out into its own class. Now the Calculator class has two dependencies: the repository, and this other class that contains some utility code. Guess what? You need to refactor the test too:

```csharp
var statistics = new StatisticsCalculator(); // <-- the new dependency
var mockRepository = new Mock<ISomeRepository>();

mockRepository.Setup(mock => mock.GetValues("foo"))
              .Returns(5);

var calculator = new Calculator(mockRepository.Object, statistics);
//                              new constructor param: ^^^^^^^^^^

var total = calculator.GetTotal();

Assert.Equals(42, total);
```

Yes, you added a `statistics` object to your test, but crucially, the call to `GetTotal()` and the assertion **remain unchanged.** This is still a refactoring job, yet you needed to change the test. Yes, the test mocks a repository object, but that is a means to an end: asserting that the total is 42.

Don't confuse code structure with behavior. The test is still asserting that the total is 42. The code structure changed, so the test changed to reflect that, but the *behavior* of the System Under Test and *assertion* remained unchanged. You are testing behavior.

Now consider a slight variation to illustrate when you are testing how code is written:

```csharp
var mockRepository = new Mock<ISomeRepository>();

mockRepository.Setup(mock => mock.GetValues("foo"))
              .Returns(5);

var calculator = new Calculator(mockRepository.Object);

var total = calculator.GetTotal();

Assert.Equals(42, total);

mock.AssertMethodWasCalled(mock => mock.GetValues("foo"));
//   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The last line where it asserts a method on a mock object got called is testing how the code was implemented. There are reasons to do this, but generally you don't need to assert that methods on a mock or other dependency got called. The test should only fail if the System Under Test didn't give you the expected result. Mocks exist to make a test deterministic when the System Under Test has potentially volatile dependencies. Mocks exist to control the System Under Test such that failures can be attributed to the behavior of the System Under Test rather than an environmental factor you cannot control.

The way you write a unit test affects whether you are verifying behavior or the way code is written. Typically you want to verify the behavior of the System Under Test and not which methods on which dependencies got called. More importantly, `refactoring != don't change the tests`. Code structure can change, making changes to your tests necessary. The conceptual idea of what you consider to be the System Under Test and the assertion should not be changed.

Think of it another way. Every test is organized into [3 phases](https://automationpanda.com/2020/07/07/arrange-act-assert-a-pattern-for-writing-good-tests/): 1) Arrange; 2) Act; and 3) Assert. Changes to the "Arrange" phase of a test are common during refactoring, and do not indicate you are testing the way code was written. If you refactor code and need to change the "Act" or "Assert" part of a test, then you are not refactoring. If you need to change the Assert when refactoring, consider for a moment if you have found a bug, or a meaningless assert.

Asserting the total equals 42 is good. Asserting that a method got called on a repository is pointless when the output should be 42. In fact, you could set up a fake method call to your repository, and if the `GetTotal()` method no longer calls the repository, your test should still pass without needing to modify your asserts.

---

Now, if you have this repository, and nobody is calling it, consider whether you need the repository, but that is a design decision out of the scope of this question, but unit tests can point you to unnecessary dependencies. Comment out a stubbed call to a mock object and the test still passes? Maybe that mock isn't necessary anymore, and its worth some analysis to see if you can remove that dependency.

Answer (score 2):

*I apologize for this being a long form answer, but the very topic of your question is one that yields benefits to you in complex business cases. Therefore, to highlight the purpose of the advice you've been given I wouldn't be able to showcase it using a very short and simple example.*

> if I write a unit test against the public surface of a class then (even if all dependencies of the said class are mocked?) I am testing the behavior of the code, and not the way it is written.

It might seem like a bit of a nitpick, but the feedback you're getting about testing is *assuming* that you already designed your class in a way that its contract (i.e. what you call public surface) is abstracted from its implementation details, in a way that the contract accurately represents a well-defined behavior (disconnected from any knowledge on how the logic to achieve this behavior would need to be implemented).

If you're currently not designing your classes like this, then you're going to see a discrepancy between what the advice says and what you're seeing.

Partly, I'm going to blame the advice here for being opaque and self-referential. It doesn't make sense to assume that your class is already designed like this, because if you were doing that already, you probably wouldn't be asking the question you're asking right now.

So let's elaborate on that hidden part of the advice you've been given.

> I've always thought about individual classes (and therefore also, in particular, their public surface) as just an implementation detail of the entire application.

The short answer here, which will require elaboration, is that not all classes have "public behavior" in the sense that it is used to describe unit testing methodologies.

A unit can be composed of multiple classes which interact with one another, but together they represent a single component. That interaction *between* these classes is considered a private implementation detail, even though some of it relies on the `public` keyword in order to allow these classes to interact with one another.

For the purpose of describing the behavior that we test, there is a difference between what is public to a *class* and what is public to the *unit under test*. Unit testing methodology focuses on the latter, and it does not care for the internal communication happening between individual classes of the unit.

For example, let's say we are building a vending machine. We need to obviously confirm that the machine we've built works before we ship it to the customer. We could test the following:

- We put a coin in the machine.
- We select the drink we want.
- We receive the drink we selected and paid for.

This is the equivalent of an integration test.

But we would also like to test *individually* if the machine is able to (a) receive money, (b) understand the customer's selection, and (c) dispense the respective drink. These are the unit tests. The reason we want to be able to test these individually is if our integration test fails, we want to know *which* part failed, which is why we need these unit tests.

For the purpose of the example, I'm going to focus on (b).

Notice that I described (b) as *understanding the customer's selection*, not as "the pressed button sends an electrical signal that matches the drink identifier". The latter is a technical implementation detail. Yes, that is what happens under the hood, but "under the hood" means private, and this behavior is described in a way that reflects its *public* expectations.

At the end of the day, what I want to test is if this scenario is correctly handled:

- I press the Sprite button
- [magic]
- The vending machine is aware I want Sprite, not Coke or Fanta.

*Early foreshadowing: notice that I've taking the original second bullet point, and I have further subdivided it into sub-bullet points.*

[magic] is not a single thing. Depending on how deeply you investigate, there are a lot of parts that interact with one another to make this happen.

- The physical button is pressed, which makes an electrical contact that was not there before, which creates a signal
- Releasing the button also must break that contact, it should not stay on indefinitely.
- That signal travels along a conductor (i.e. electrical wire), and it reaches the controller (i.e. the thing all the buttons are hooked up to).
- The controller is able to discern *which* button is sending a signal, find the related price of the product, compare the price and the money entered into the machine.
- If successful, it sends a different signal through to the correct dispenser (because a specific button should map to a specific dispenser).

But a lot of these are technical implementation details. For example, it doesn't matter that we're using a physical button. We could be using a touch screen, an NFC reader, a voice assistant, ... and the process would be the same. We might currently be making selections using buttons, but we need to design our test around selections, not buttons specifically, because we're interested in the public behavior (the ability to select), not the specific implementation (physically pressing a button).

A more correctly abstracted test design would be:

- **Arrange**

  - Unit under test - We instantiate all of the components that are necessary to convert a drink selection to a dispenser signal, i.e. button, wire, controller; and we wire them up the way they're supposed to be.
  - Mocked state - The price of the item is $2
  - Mocked state - The money counter component is telling you that the customer has put $2 in the machine
  - Mocked spy - A fake dispenser is made, which is going to report back to us which drink it was told to dispense.
- **Act**

  - We select Sprite
- **Assert**

  - The dispenser is told to dispense a Sprite drink.
  - The dispenser is not told to dispense any other drinks.

If tomorrow we change to using a touch screen, we're going to have to make changes to the "unit under test" section, because that's inevitable. This step instantiates the real components, so any change made to the components being used will obviously require updating.

**But the test remains the same for everything else**. That is the point.

If your test had been designed around the concept of a button, the entire test would need to be rewritten. Instead, by designing the test around the concept of a *selection* (which currently happens to be done via a button), we are able to swap that button out with minimal impact to the test.

---

To conclude, I want to refer back to the thing I already foreshadowed above:

> *Early foreshadowing: notice that I've taking the original second bullet point, and I have further subdivided it into sub-bullet points.*

Taking a complex orchestration and breaking it down into simpler constituent parts is the essence of software development, and more importantly it is a recursive process. You can keep applying this to subcomponents, and you should keep doing this until each individual subcomponent is trivially definable, implementable and testable.

If you're struggling to define it, implement it, or test it; you probably need to break it down further.

**But you need to know when to stop.** You can always break things down further, but it's not going to keep making things easier. At some point, further decomposition starts making things more difficult. This should be avoided. It is a form of dogmatic programming, i.e. decomposing things for the sake of decomposing them, not for the sake of it actually having a practical benefit.

When you said this:

> I've always thought about individual classes as just an implementation detail of the entire application.

It sound like you're immediately doing a *full* decomposition in a single go, i.e:

> The whole application => specific classes

But it would be more helpful to do this in individual steps, e.g.:

> The whole application => a bounded context => a component => one or more specific classes

The amount of steps there are is not universally answerable, it very much depends on your context. Some applications are really simple, some are really complex. This obviously changes the amount of layers there are.

Generally speaking, the implementation lives on the last step in this chain (i.e. "one or more specific classes"), but the definition of a "unit under test" tends to live on the **second to last** step in this chain (i.e. "a component").

**This disconnect between the level on which your write your implementation and the level on which you design your test, I suspect, is the core part of what led you to post this question.**

If you do the decomposition step by step, you'll be more attuned to how the initial big picture (which describes your business requirements) slowly morphs into your specific implementation details, and this will be the indicator that helps you identify what should be labeled as a "unit" for the purpose of "unit testing".

If you don't decompose it enough, it's more an integration test than it is a unit test. If you decompose it too much, your unit tests will actually become "class tests" that are so intwined with your implementation details that you're going to have to continually rewrite the tests, which is where the process is no longer beneficial to you.

I don't know your specific experience level, but finding that line is very difficult. Experienced senior developers still struggle to sometimes clearly identify these lines. Don't worry about getting it objectively correct. Just try to do better when you realize that there's an imperfection.

Comment: *"We could be using a touch screen, an NFC reader, a voice assistant, ... and the process would be the same."* - the same for who or what? I find it very hard to believe that a test harness designed around the idea of a keypad entry (that being the public surface), would work equally well with a machine expecting voice input at the public surface. The only thing that is the "same" here is the conceptual idea of an item selection (i.e. the similarity exists purely in the human mind) - there's nothing the same mechanically about the *interface* under test.

Comment: "*The reason we want to be able to test these individually is if our integration test fails, we want to know which part failed, which is why we need these unit tests.*" - I've seen people using this argument to support the idea that each class and each method (*maybe* even private methods) must be specifically tested (if I understand these people correctly). A unit test must test a single unit *of code*, because if a unit test fails, then we must know *precisely* which part of code is erroneous, with no further debugging. (cont)

Comment: So a failing unit test should, ideally, point me to the precise method that needs fixing. Obviously such tests are not sufficient, so on top of unit tests we must have component level tests. If all unit tests pass, but a component level test fails, then we know the error lies not in any particular method, but rather in the interaction between methods within a single component. On top of component level tests we must have integration tests and on top of this we must have full end-to-end tests. (cont)

Comment: But tests should be pushed downwards: if something can be tested by a test that lies lower in Cohn's pyramid of testing, it must (so that a failing test at level X shows there is an error in the way components at level X+1 interact, and not in a component at level X+1, because this would mean a test at level X+1 would have to fail instead). In this way I need to have a very comprehensive test suite that reflects Cohn's pyramid of testing.

Comment: To be clear, I don't *like* the above advice, mainly because writing such an extremely comprehensive and multi-level suite of tests seems to me to be extremely costly and annoying to write, hence my current stream of questions...

Comment: Also, I'm not 100% sure now, but didn't Feathers in his 'Working effectively with legacy code' also argue for writing tests for each *class*? (Sorry for wall of comments)

Comment: >  not in any particular method, but rather in the interaction between methods within a single component.

That's not technically possible - the methods don't interact autonomously, they only interact if one of the methods (or another method) tells codes for that interaction. If the interaction is wrong then there must be code *somewhere* that is wrong, and in principle that could can be unit tested.

Comment: @bdsl You're right. Let me try to correct myself: The bug cannot be understood by just looking at a particular class, but only by looking at this class and a 3rd party API or several our classes at the same time.

Comment: @Steve: Dial back to the purpose of the test that is being discussed: when I select a specific drink, assuming the appropriate money was entered, that specific drink is dispensed. The manner of selection is not relevant for describing the test's purpose. Focusing on the mechanics of the hardware (or, stepping out of the analogy, the specific classes that a unit is composed out of) is precisely what you _shouldn't_ do when designing tests, because it renders your test tightly coupled to a specific implementation as opposed to the more abstracted behavior that you're trying to test for.

Comment: @gaazkam _"I've seen people using this argument to support the idea that each class and each method (maybe even private methods) must be specifically tested (if I understand these people correctly)."_ The argument itself is correct but it's being applied dogmatically and overzealously. You shouldn't dig down to the atomic level, this is way too far across the boundary of reasonability, and going past that line gets you in the territory that this question points out (constant need for refactoring)

Comment: @gaazkam: _"didn't Feathers in his 'Working effectively with legacy code' also argue for writing tests for each class?"_ Beware of the trap of simplicity. Advice uses simple examples because it wants to be concise and to the point, but some advanced techniques are only valuable when applied to sufficiently complex systems. In simple cases, a unit _can_ be represented as a single class, at which point you are indeed focusing on a class. But the focus remains on the unit. If the units consists of more classes, the test focus stays with the unit, not the individual classes.

Comment: @Flater, to my eye you are conflating things that exist in our minds, with the things that exist as mechanical operations. There's no way of devising a test harness for drinks selection on a vending machine, that doesn't look different depending on whether it is keypad entry or voice entry. The purpose is the same for us, but the mechanics of the machine and the test harness are completely different. As I've also remarked beneath Ewan's answer (with more explanation), the point of tests is to be tightly coupled - the looser they are, the sloppier they are at detecting errors and regressions.

Comment: @Steve: It appears we disagree ideologically about what kind of coupling we should aim for in testing, so let's just leave it at disagreeing. I do want to point out that you're not really seeing the wood for the trees in my vending machine analogy; any constraint that only relates to physical devices is obviously not part of the analogy here.

Comment: @Flater, my interpretation of the vending machine analogy, is that you're presenting two interfaces whose purpose (of making an item selection) is obviously the same, and suggesting that because their purposes are the same then the same test should be applicable. My rebuttal to this is that the purposes may be the same to the human beholder, but the mechanical form of the public interfaces (and the manner of interacting with them) is not. And the identity of form is what counts for automatic tests, not the similarity of purpose (of which a machine has no grasp).

Comment: @Steve: What you seem to be glossing over is that the purpose of the test I'm discussing is not "does this selection component work the way I intend it to", it's "does the selection make it from the selection component to the correct dispenser?". Those are different tests with different focuses. Yes, I agree with you that a button-specific test will obviously be impacted if we do away with buttons and use touchscreens instead, but the test I was discussing was _not_ a test that focuses on buttons specifically.

Comment: @Steve Consider the context of OP's question, whereby their tests are currently so granular that they break when every minute implementation detail breaks. This comes with an implied statement that these minute implementation detail changes _shouldn't_ be impacting the tests, hence my answer of pulling back the tightness of the tests' coupling to a level where the test suite does not tie itself to implementation details which you don't explicitly care to test for. Tight test coupling is not a matter of picking either extreme, it's a matter of finding the right spot for you on the spectrum.

Comment: @Steve: Based on your comments, you are considering the button itself a valuable unit to put under test. That's perfectly fine. But my example very intentionally frames itself as the button being a private implementation detail of the larger "product selection" component, and with an intention to test the product selection component, not the underlying bits. I could apply the same to your button test: do you wish to write a test for the metal bits in the button that connect to make a contact? What about the spring that makes the button pop back up? Or would you just test the button itself?

Comment: @Flater, it's *your* vending machine analogy. If the keypad or microphone isn't the *public interface* in this analogy, then what is? Your fallacy as it appears to me, is that you're treating buttons and microphones as "private implementations" of a broader "item selection" concept. That concept exists only in people's minds. If I was making a robotic test harness for a vending machine, it would have speakers for the microphone interface and some kind of actuator for the keypad interface. There is no other separate "item selection" component or *public* interface in such a machine. (1/2)

Comment: In short, you're not distinguishing between the things which you as the designer understand to be the same because they have the same purpose, and things which are mechanically the same and are therefore suitable to be automatically tested by the same test machinery (without the test machinery being specifically adapted to either). There's no equivalence of mechanical form between keypads and microphones. (2/2)

Comment: @Steve: You keep arguing that it's turtles all the way down. You're not wrong but it's pointless to keep pointing this out. Unless you are talking about the literal subatomic particles that make up the universe, anything you deal with is always a composition of smaller pieces. But there is a line of reasonability as to how deep you need to dig into things before it starts being irrelevant for your current use case. I picked an example where the subcomponents were clearly delineated, specifically so that I could highlight that some tests operate on a level higher than the lowest possible level.

Comment: @Steve: [..] Had I reframed my analogy to be one level deeper, then the subcomponent tests (i.e. one level down from _that_ deeper level) would have been physical material tests, which are so very different that it would break the analogy significantly. You keep trying to treat this analogy as a real world exercise, completely sidestepping what is being conveyed in this answer. Comments are intended to ask for clarifications, not to take a given analogy and reinterpret it to be something different. What you're doing is not contributing to this answer and missing its point entirely.

Comment: @Flater, my thesis is very simple. Interfaces are an implementation of a design, which is subject to change. Such change is quite normal and desirable. Tests are also a form of auxiliary implementation, and must be fitted to correspond with both the primary interfaces and internals under test. If you change anything about the primary implementation, you will have to review the fitting of the tests for continued correspondence, and quite probably change the test implementation to re-fit the altered primary implementation. Now that's my thesis. (1/2)

Comment: I accept your apparent point that things don't need to be tested at the lowest possible level of parts. But now you seem to be refusing to accept my thesis in relation to the very *highest* level in the vending machine, too. I think you're going around in circles trying to deny that tests need to be fitted and re-fitted, or to imply that such need of fitting and re-fitting is a sign of a design flaw. And I don't mean just you - it's a common refrain from many here, and from pundits. And it's completely wrong. If we've exhausted discussion then I'll stop, but those are the issues. (2/2)

Answer (score 1):

From a certain perspective you are right: Unit tests test internal parts of an application and are therefore always coupled to implementation details. If the entire internal architecture of the application is rewritten, all unit tests would become obsolete - even if the external behavior of the application remains the same.

But consider a code base developed strictly following the [Open-closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle). In such a project unit tests would *never* become invalid because public interfaces are never changed, only extended. You would need to add unit tests when adding new functionality, but you would never need to alter existing unit tests.

In reality, most project does not follow the open-closed principle strictly, and allows changes to public interfaces when it is deemed to improve the overall architecture. In those case you would have to change test and code at the same time, which is always risky. But if there is good test coverage, there will be a level of redundancy which should catch those bugs.

For example, imagine you have a class A which depend on class B:

```
 [ A ] -> [ B ]
```

If you follow test-driven development, you would have tests for both A and B. But imagine you have to change the public interface of B. You would have to make code changes to both A and B and modify the tests for B. But the tests for A would not need to change, which means they should catch any bugs introduced by the change. So as long as you are able to change one class at a time, you can safely make changes to public interfaces.

Your assume that you would often have to make changes to the public interfaces many classes at the same time. I don't think this should be the case if the code is loosely coupled and generally follow good design principles. The ideal is to make many small changes incrementally and having all tests be green between each change.

Comment: *"a code base developed strictly following the Open-closed principle"* - I think you're misunderstanding that. Meyer (who was writing over 35 years ago) did not devise a method of software design that, if followed "strictly", guarantees no design error and no future re-adaptation in the system of interfaces. Rather, he was describing principles or ideals to which interface designs should conform. But that's begging the very question of achieving those ideals - we change the system of interfaces because we find it is *not* ideal, or has ceased to be ideal as circumstances have changed. (1/2)

Comment: *"The ideal is to make many small changes incrementally and having all tests be green between each change."* - it would certainly be ideal, but I find often that even "small" changes can require tweaks all over a codebase, and that's before even considering real architectural upheavals when something originally quite simple has to be revamped to cope with a considerably more complicated new requirement. I don't think any development method is living in the real world when it assumes changes are only ever incremental, local, and that the software really works after each increment. (2/2)

Comment: @Steve: The open-closed principle is strictly adhered to in for example the .net base class library in order to not break backwards compatibility even across major version. AFAIK they only accept backwards compatibility breakage for security issues. Of course this does not mean the BCL does not have any mistakes or examples of bad design, it just means that they can't fix design mistakes by altering or removing public interfaces, only by adding new public interfaces. Classes and method may be deprecated when there is a better alternative, but are not removed.

Comment: @JacquesB This approach is understandable, but it does have its downsides: mess will gradually accumulate. Programming language standard libraries may have no other choice, but the situation in C++ clearly shows what this eventually leads to.

Comment: @gaazkam: Absolutely, and I will not recommend this approach for the typical application development. I mention it is an example of how it is possible to develop and refactor without ever having to alter existing unit tests. For most application development it is better to change public interfaces when appropriate and update tests as necessary. But you shouldn't have to update both many interfaces and many tests as the same time, this is too much risk.

Comment: @JacquesB, our argument is that, if you want to actually maintain your application current and coherent, then the interfaces often will have to change. Microsoft keeps the interfaces stable because millions of developers and deployed applications depend on them. But it sounds like an absurdity to me to argue that an in-house application should immediately go into legacy mode, just so you don't upset the tests. The darn tests were supposed to make changes easier and safer according to the proponents! Not fix things so that we daren't now change the things we want to change!

Answer (score -2):

You assert that refactoring will modify the public surface of classes and hence break unit tests, but don't say why that won't break integration tests.

An integration test is just a unit test with less mocking.

Even an end to end test, where you say test "when i click on the button a thing happens" is obviously going to break if you move the button.

Instead of thinking of individual classes as implementation details of an application, think of them as library classes that perform an operation you are using in your application. You never change the interface to Math.SquareRoot, you just assume its always going to work. Why do your treat your own classes differently?

Comment: *"but don't say why that won't break integration tests."* - in his previous question, he did in fact explain, along the lines that because integration tests have more internal mass and less surface area hooked by tests, it's more likely that an alteration would be purely internal and wouldn't therefore affect the tests. Not endorsing that logic, but just stating it. (1/2)

Comment: *"You never change the interface to Math.SquareRoot, you just assume its always going to work. Why do your treat your own classes differently?"* - I would suggest it may be because the workings of basic mathematical operators have been settled over centuries by people who spent their whole lives in mathematical study, are highly general, and are tested in use by billions of users. Whereas the same cannot be said about the design of the average application codebase - much of which will have been written this year by one person with next to no experience of anything. (2/2)

Comment: to me the previous question doesn't really cover the difference, just asserts that there is one. The reason you don't change the interface on sqrt isn't because the definition is settled, (your average sqrt doesn't handle complex numbers) its because you treat the library as a completed component of your application. My point is that you should treat your own application components, classes, in the same way. Then the answer to the question is clear.

Comment: I don't follow that logic myself, because the system of components and classes in an application is not necessarily fixed or "completed". I don't see much of a natural analogy between the relative stability of standard mathematical tools and operators, and the stability of things which are written bespoke for specific business applications.

Comment: I'm not saying there will never be any refactoring, you might change your Maths library and have to refactor your code to a new interface, you might have a higher chance of having to change the interface to myComponent. But if you treat components as components instead of my code and external code, then you don't have this question of unit tests being implementation tests. They are behaviour tests for a component

Comment: I think interfaces are part of the implementation of an application design. Although I understand the interface/internal distinction, I think they are both forms of implementation, which embed design decisions for the time being, and around which tests have to be fitted (and re-written, not refactored, if anything changes). I think the relevance of the interface/internal distinction is that only interfaces are hookable by automatic tests, and internals are not. But I don't agree that useful tests are fitted only to interfaces and not fitted to the internals. (1/3)

Comment: It's often not feasible to exhaustively/brute force test an interface for all possible interactions, because it would produce a large number of test cases (even in what are pathetically simple cases, like just testing the behaviour of the dyadic addition operator for a 32-bit fixed-width integer, there would be 2bn * 2bn test cases to submit to the interface), and it would often just produce a chaos of results (and beg the question of which cases have passed or failed correctly, and which results are symptoms of error). (2/3)

Comment: Real tests are not written like this. They are written around crafting an exemplary subset of inputs which get submitted to the interface, which the programmer tailors to the internals to ensure that the subset covers strange cases, thresholds, exceptional codepaths, and so on. In this way, even though the test only interacts through the interface, it is still designed around the internals. The only time they aren't designed to the internals is when the test maker doesn't have access to the internals, but the result is almost certainly a looser and poorer quality test. Tell me I'm wrong. (3/3)

Comment: think you've got the wrong end of the stick somewhere.

Comment: its generally accepted that "test the interface", is the correct approach, but its not really relevant to my point

Comment: I think it is relevant to the wider confusion. I'm heavily condensing and abbreviating my thoughts. "Test the interface" may be conventional wisdom, but as I say, if that means not tailoring the test to the internals which are under test, then the result will be a sloppy test. Obviously, sloppy tests need to be changed less often when internals change, but by being sloppy they are poorer quality - less effective at detecting initial faults, and less effective at detecting regression when something is altered. Brute forcing the interface is not an option either, as I said. (1/2)

Comment: Btw I do acknowledge the point you made that tests are supposed to test "behaviour" at the level of a whole "component". My point is that the internals completely determine the relevant behaviour - they set the shape around which the "exemplary subset of interactions" (submitted to the interface by the test, for the purpose of checking the correctness of the results or reaction) must be fitted, if it is to be a tight test. (2/2)

Comment: possibly, but they are only conceptually coupled in that you know "nulls might fail internally" so you write the test, you could refactor the internals to something where you  know 100% nulls are handled and dont need a test, but the test will still pass.

Comment: the OP is saying that "unit tests" on classes are all brittle because the interface on classes changes often. im  saying, "not if you treat the classes as sub components of your system, rather than nice ways to package what might otherwise be private methods", ie like Math.Sqrt, or String.Format or RandomHelpfullPackage.DoTheThing

Answer (score -2):

By definition, refactoring changes the way code is written without changing is outside behaviour. There’s a famous book called “Refactoring” and thats his authors definition. Martin Fowler his name.

You can make very useful changes that intentionally change the outside behaviour and therefore break init tests, but that is not refactoring.

Now a class can have private methods, not part of the interface, so they should have no unit tests. You can change them and it is still refactoring- obviously only as long as callers that are unit tested are changed accordingly.

And remember that at some point you are actually implementing your module, and while your private methods are irrelevant to users of your module, they are very relevant to you as the author of the module. So you may very well have private unit tests, so that any user of your private methods (in other words, you and the module and anyone taking over maintenance of your module) can rely on your private methods.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if we agree on definitions. Assume I make changes to some classes in such a way that the behavior of public methods of these classes changes. However, the behavior of the entire application whose code contains those classes does not change. Is this refactoring for you? I'd call this 'refactoring', but I start suspecting that others might not call this refactoring on the basis that public surface of some classes changed.

Comment: What is the scope you are looking at? If you are looking at the scope of the application, it is Refactoring. If you are looking at the scope of the class, it is rewriting. By the way, I notice a lot of emphasis on classes in your questions and comments. I would like to remind you that object-orientation is about *objects*, not classes. In fact, OOP isn't really about objects either, it is about *messaging*, i.e., what happens *between* the objects. Likewise, you seem to be under the impression that unit tests test classes or methods. They don't. They test *units* (of behavior).

Comment: @JörgWMittag, but if refactorings don't require tests to be changed, and rewritings do, then how can it be entirely in the eye of the beholder? Either the tests actually have to be changed, or not - it can't depend purely on how the programmer thinks. And if "units" are not methods or even classes, but something as large as a *module* with its own defined external interface and consisting of many classes internally, then it's fair to acknowledge that many practitioners do end up testing individual classes and methods in isolation, not just whole modules.

Comment: @gaazkam: In your example, that's generally not what's called "public" in relation to testing strategies. If your application still behaves identically, then the public behavior hasn't changed, by the very definition of what public behavior is. I think you're conflating the `public` keyword in a class with the "public" in "public behavior". They are similar but not the very same. The "public" in "public behavior" is application-scoped (= integration tests) or component-scoped (= unit tests), it is not inherently class-scoped. It's only-class scoped when a component is made up out of one class.